# Node js Passport y bcryptjs UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: nodejs, passport, bcryptjs

Hola amigos estoy tratando de encryptar unos datos , pero no sé porque no lo puedo hacer :s

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const knex = require('../db');
const helpers = require('../lib/handlebars');

passport.use('local.signup', new LStrategy({
    usernameField: 'name',
    passwordField: 'pass',
    passReqToCallback: true }, async (req, userName, pass, done) => {

    //console.log(req.body);
    const mail = req.body.mail;
    const newUser = {
        userName,
        mail: mail
    };

    newUser.pass = await helpers.encryptPass(pass);

    const query = knex().insert(newUser).into('USERS_');

    query.then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });

}));
```

Seguido de :

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const helpers = {};

helpers.encryptPass = async (pass) =>{
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10); // genera los saltos de encriptación
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(pass,salt);
    return hash;
};
```

Este es el error que me manda

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: helpers.encryptPass is not a function

Alguien sabe qué es lo que me estoy perdiendo ?

Comment: ¿ Seguro que es ese código ? Primero haces `const helpers = require('../lib/handlebars');` ... ¿ y luego `const helpers = {};` ?

Comment: si tengo un > module.exports = helpers al final

Comment: Deberías de aclarar la pregunta: ¿ Eso son 2 archivos o solo 1 ? ¿ Donde está el `module.exports`? ¿ que archivo hace `require( )` al otro ? No se, si el problema está en `helpers`, se me ocurre que deberías mostrar **todo** lo referente a dicha variable. Igual incluso deberías mostrar un [mcve].